# Very Basic setAttribute on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, element, setattribute

I'm very beginner in JavaScript and I can't understand why in this simple code, appears in the console *color.setAttribute is not a function*

```html
<style>
 .red {color:red;}
 .blue { color: blue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="red">Hello World</p>
<script>
 var color = document.getElementsByClassName("red");
 color.setAttribute("class","blue");
</script>
```

To my knowledge when declare the variable *color*, I create an *element object* and I can use the *method* : setAttribute.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if my question is to silly.

Comment: Incidentally, jQuery works exactly like you wish: `$('.red').addClass('blue');`

Comment: Thank you, now I understand, and never thought to receive such a quick answers, thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("red")` returns a dom object which is array like object. so you should write the following.

```
var color=document.getElementsByClassName("red")[0];
color.setAttribute("class","blue");
```

Comment: Technically, it doesn't return an array, but rather an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which is an array-like object that does have a `.length` property like an array and supports `[i]` indexing like an array, but does not have any of the usual array methods such as `.forEach()` or `.slice()`.

Comment: You can use the edit link in your answer to improve it.

Comment: As you wish. @jfriend00 :)

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`. You've to use an index to select a node from the node list.

```
var color = document.getElementsByClassName("red")[0]; // the first element
```